# Java how to replace last character of string to specific character

Tags: java, string

I was having some problem when trying to format the string. So basically I got enqueue and dequeue and it was working fine now. Here is the code:

```
public String toString(){
    String str = "[";
    for(int i = front; i<= rear; i++){
        str += Q[i] + ",";  
    }

    if(str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(str.length()-1)==','){
        str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
    }

    return str;
}
```

I wanted the result to be like **[1,2,3,4]**. However, I have no idea how to replace the last **","** to **"]"**. The current problem is it returns me **[1,2,3,4,** and that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change :

```
for(int i = front; i<= rear; i++){
    str += Q[i] + ",";  
}
```

to :

```
for(int i = front; i< rear; i++){
    str += Q[i] + ",";  
}
str+=Q[rear] + "]";
```

also it is better to use `StringBuilder.append()` instead of `str +=`, Because String is `immutable` and every time you use `str+=` it creates new instance of your `str` Object

with `StringBuilder` it will be :

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.append("[");
for(int i = front; i<= rear; i++){
    str.append(Q[i] + ",");  
}
str.append(Q[rear] + "]");
```

Comment: @Denise dont forget to mark this as answer if it works

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
String str = "[";
for(int i = front; i< rear; i++){
    str += Q[i] + ",";  
}
str += Q[rear] + "]";
```

Of course, I'd use StringBuilder instead of String concatenation :

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(128);
str.append('[');
for(int i = front; i< rear; i++){
    str.append(Q[i]);
    str.append(',');  
}
if (rear > front) {
    str.append(Q[rear]);
}
str.append(']'); 
return str.toString();
```

Comment: I thought this line str += Q[i] + "]";  should be inside the for loop? If not it will tell me cannot find i

Comment: @Denise You are correct. It would only work if `i` is declared prior to the loop. You can replace it with `str += Q[rear] + "]"` though.

Comment: @Denise though I would prefer the StringBuilder version, which is more efficient. Please note that it also handles the case of `rear <= front`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.replaceAll`

```
string.replaceAll(",(?=[^,]*$)", "]");
```

OR

```
string.replaceAll("(?m),$", "]");
```

Comment: But using this my other "," in the str will be replaced as well.

Comment: no, it won't.. It must replace the last comma. see https://regex101.com/r/dN3rP0/1

Answer (score 1):

```
public String toString(){
    String str = "[";
    for(int i = front; i<= rear; i++){
        if (i == rear)
            str += Q[i] + ","; 
        else
            str += Q[i] + "]";
    }

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use concatenation `+=` inside loops

```
for (...){
    //...
    resultString += newString
    //...
}
```

to create string result. This way each time you execute this code it creates new String which needs to copy value from `resultString` and add `newString`.

Instead use proper tools like `StringBuilder` and its `append` method. This prevents copying previous result each time (which can take some time) and places newString in bigger buffer. So make your code more like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (...){
    sb.append(newString);
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Also if you want to add delimiter like `,` you can use `new StringJoiner(delimiter)` (added in Java 8) or if you want to add prefix and suffix like `[` and `]` use `new StringJoinder(delimiter, prefix, suffix)`.

So your code can look more or less like:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]");
for(int i = front; i<= rear; i++){
   sj.add(Q[i]);  
}
return sj.toString();
```

or even

```
return IntStream
       .rangeClosed(fron, rear)
       .mapToObj(i->Q[i])
       .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the new, Java 8 only style:

```
Arrays.stream(Arrays.copyOfRange(Q, front, rear)).collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]");
```

Which implicitly creates a StringJoiner with the parameters passed to Collectors.joining(), *delimiter*, *prefix*, *suffix*.
While not specifically answering your question as it is phrased, it solves the actual problem you're facing.

Comment: Problem here is that OP is using `front` - `rear` range of elements from `Q`.

Comment: Why would you want to create separate copy of range? You can simply use `IntStream` with specified range and map this `int` values to `Q` elements, just like shown at the end of my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30682654/1393766